# Incomplete WSDL - Account class is missing a child relationship with a custom object

Tags: java, wsdl, salesforce

I generated an Enterprise WSDL, in which the Account class has a bunch of fields and relationships with custom and native objects, but does not have the relationship I need to use in my code.

Any ideas why it's omitted?   I know that the WSDL is generated based on the permissions of the user creating it, but that's not the case here.

More details, if needed:

Custom object name is "Attachment_Category__c".
It's child relationship to the Account is called **R00N30000000vdrhEAA**.

I expect to see the following field declaration in the Account class:

```
    private com.sforce.soap.enterprise.QueryResult R00N30000000vdrhEAA;
```

similar to already present following ones:

```
    private com.sforce.soap.enterprise.QueryResult notesAndAttachments; //standard object
    private com.sforce.soap.enterprise.QueryResult legal_Documents__r;  //custom object
```

I also expect a **getR00N30000000vdrhEAA()** method in the Account class, same as it currently has **getLegal_Documents__r()**, but it's not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go into setup and give the relationship a real name.

Comment: Yep, that was it.   Interestingly, once you name the child relationship properly, you don't have to go back and update your existing Apex code with the new relationship names - Apex will run the queries with the system-generated names (like R00N30000000vdrhEAA), or the custom names (like Attachment_Categories__r).  Neat.  Except now, that the relationship has a real name, we can use it in the API.